# How to add Drawer without AppBar by clicking on the icon Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using `extendBodyBehindAppBar` and creating an `AppBar` by extending `PreferredSizeWidget`. I have a `burgerMenu` (`buttonIcon`) icon in `appBar` file that needs to be clicked to open the `Drawer`. Tell me how to correctly implement the opening of the `Drawer` in my case, without using the standard version with the `AppBar`?

**home**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: LogoAppBar(buttonIcon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.burgerMenu)),
      body: const HomeBody(),
    );
  }
```

**appBar**

```
class LogoAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  LogoAppBar({Key? key, required this.buttonIcon, this.onPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  final SvgPicture buttonIcon;
  final Function()? onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SvgPicture logoSvg = SvgPicture.asset(
        '...logo.svg',
        height: 40);

    double horizontalPadding = 24;

    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: horizontalPadding),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                logoWidget(logoSvg, horizontalPadding),
                SizedBox(child: buttonIcon),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget logoWidget(SvgPicture logoSvg, double horPadding) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: logoSvg,
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(60);
}
```

Comment: where are you adding the drawer?

Comment: I need to open the Drawer in the appBar file by clicking on the buttonIcon (burgerMenu). That's why I wanted to know how to do it right?

Comment: Are you calling drawer on scaffold?  like `drawer: Drawer()`

Comment: I don't call Drawer yet. I just wanted to know how best to do this in my case?

Comment: You can try it on parent scaffold, the 1st one of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GlobalKey` to open the drawer and open using  `myScaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();`.

Make sure to wrap you `buttonIcon` with tappable widget like `GestureDetector`/`InkWell` and add `onPressed`.

```dart
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _sKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _sKey ,
      appBar: LogoAppBar(
        onPressed: () {
          debugPrint("open");
          _sKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
        },
      ),
      drawer: const Drawer(),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      //...
```

Comment: Thanks, tell me, is it necessary to use key or can I just Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer() ? How to

Comment: using `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()` will throw an error of not having `context`, the general solution of this error is wrapping with `Builder` to ensure the context but in this case, `appBar` only accept `PreferredSizeWidget`(general) widget. therefore, using key is better option in this case.

Comment: If you look at my code, then in home I create a key and pass it to the LogoAppBar class and use it there to open the Drawer. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: We don't need to pass our `_sKey`  because we are using a callback method here. and about `LogoAppBar({Key? key,...)` it is widget key, sometimes we need to pass this to work properly, like having same two statefullwiget on state changes. You can check [this video from flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html)